# What is the difference between AnimationListener and AnimatorListener?

Tags: android, animation

I would like to use the `AnimatorListenerAdapter`, specified here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorListenerAdapter.html

But, it implements the `AnimatorListener` interface. On a `View`, such as an `ImageView`, there is a method called `setAnimationListener()`, but it takes, as a parameter, an `AnimationListener`. There doesn't seem to be an associated `AnimationListenerAdapter` available.

My question is what is the difference between `AnimatorListener` and `AnimationListener`, and why do the two separate interfaces exist? It seems like they both provide the same functionality. The only difference I can see is that one of them was introduced in a later API version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AnimationListener` is for the old style `View` animations, while `AnimatorListener` is for the new (as of 3.0) `Animator` APIs.

All `AnimatorListenerAdapter` does is implement the `AnimatorListener` interface with no functionality. You can easily create your own `AnimationListenerAdapter` in the same way by creating a public non-final class which implements `AnimationListener` with no functionality.

Comment: Sure, you're absolutely right that I can create my own adapter easily, I just was hoping that I didn't have to do that even. (I'm very lazy when it comes to programming.) :>

Answer (score 1):

For lazy people as us :

```
import android.view.animation.Animation

/**
 * Adapter to reduce code implementation of Animation.AnimationListener when there are unused
 * functions.
 */
open class AnimationListenerAdapter: Animation.AnimationListener {

    /**
     *
     * Notifies the start of the animation.
     *
     * @param animation The started animation.
     */
    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {

    }

    /**
     *
     * Notifies the end of the animation. This callback is not invoked
     * for animations with repeat count set to INFINITE.
     *
     * @param animation The animation which reached its end.
     */
    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {

    }

    /**
     *
     * Notifies the repetition of the animation.
     *
     * @param animation The animation which was repeated.
     */
    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation) {

    }
```

}